# Android: Finding a view's id by supplying its own id

Tags: android

If I have `ImageButton myPicture`. Can I say `myPicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(myPicture.getId());`?

Is there anyway I can implement this?

Comment: Why...? If `myPicture` exists, and has a valid Id, why would you be recreating it?

Comment: No but you can go in R.java file, find the int value of myPicture and use in findviewbyid(int value);

Comment: @MaulikSheth Yeah the problem with that is I have 64 ImageButtons and I dont want to write 64 lines of code. There must be a way I can find all their views using a for loop

Comment: @Clay You can't as you need to initialise them somehow first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `myPicture` object already exists, why would you be recreating it?

Yes, this will work, if the `myPicture` objects has already been created in the app context, or been previously reference to an Id in your layout.

You can not use this as a first time initialization, because the object is null, you have to first get it from the layout.

**Edit**

In response to your comment above, instead of doing this 64 times, you could use an XML file to create a template layout, and then in your Java code, inflate the template layout inside of a loop, adding in the required information.

Comment: so if my layout file is R.layout.myLayout. How would I get all 64 ImageButtons that are in it. Would I need to write 64 lines of code? I cant use a for loop?

Comment: Instead of having 64 image buttons, have a single image button that you duplicate inside of a loooooop.

Comment: But the ImageButtons are different, they have different Ids, ie, android:id="@+id/cell01"

Comment: you can change id in for loop by ``imageButton.setId(i+1)`` but you should know that ``id`` must be positive

Comment: But the prefect way to do that is to use ``ListView`` or ``GridView``
you will have your XML layout with ``ImageButton``and then you will inflate it in ``ListView`` with changing adapter which will hold list of ``ImageButton`` and there you can chnage the ``imageButton``  more on ``ListView`` see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you can't since `myPicture` in the right operand is still null this can cause `NullPointerException` and yet you didn't catch any `ImageButton` view
you either create one programmatically

```
ImageButton imageButton=new ImageButton(this);
```

or you draw it on layout XML file and this find it by using `findViewById(R.id.imageButtonId)`

this will actually create a view of `ImageButton` then you can select it but by your way there isn't view to select yet